# How can I switch between databases in startup

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, deployment

I have an MVP c# application where I have an SQLLite database for development purposes and a SQLServer database for deployment purposes. Whenever I try to build it with the SQL server database, it shows: "Build failed."

I am a student Informatica and our teacher says that we could solve our problem by using a simple "if else" to switch between development and deployment but we have no idea how.

We have already used dependency injection and migrations.

Here are 2 images with the error:

1) [image: Build error]

2) [image]

3) This is the error:

> Startup.cs(41,71): error CS1061: 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseMySQL' and no accessible extension method 'UseMySQL' accepting a first argument of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/cityofideas_dotnet/cityofideas/cityofideas.csproj]
>   Startup.cs(42,76): error CS1061: 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseMySQL' and no accessible extension method 'UseMySQL' accepting a first argument of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/cityofideas_dotnet/cityofideas/cityofideas.csproj] Build FAILED.

4) Finally

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.CommandException: Build failed.
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Project.Build()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.RootCommand.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
>   Build failed.

Please help us!

Comment: Can you provide the code you tried to achieve your goal ?

Comment: Thats a lot of dark hard to read picture spam

Comment: Contrast FTW ... Please post error messages as text, not as image.

Comment: Usually, you'll have two places where you need to take into account which database you are using: Selecting a Connector/Driver (probably in DI setup) and in the Connection-String. The latter can be handled by using different app.config files for each environment. The former can be done for example with a preprocessor flag, if the DI framework doesn't already support having different environments. For writing up an answer, we would need to know a little more about your implementation and frameworks used.

Comment: @Fildor so I should make another app.config file for deployment (development is already there). And then I should use a preprocessor flag and an if else to determine which app.settings I should use? Thanks for the information!